# How can I run a system command in Perl asynchronously?

Tags: perl

I currently have a Perl script that runs an external command on the system, gathers the output, and performs some action based on what was returned.  Right now, here is how I run this (where $cmd is a string with the command setup):

```
@output = `$cmd`;
```

I'd like to change this so if the command hangs and does not return a value after so much time then I kill the command.  How would I go about running this asynchronously?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really just need to put a timeout on a given system call that is a much simpler problem than asynchronous programming.

All you need is alarm() inside of an eval() block.

Here is a sample code block that puts these into a subroutine that you could drop into your code.  The example calls sleep so isn't exciting for output, but does show you the timeout functionality you were interested in.
Output of running it is:

> /bin/sleep 2 failure: timeout at
>   ./time-out line 15.

```
$ cat time-out
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my $timeout = 1;
my @cmd = qw(/bin/sleep 2);
my $response = timeout_command($timeout, @cmd);
print "$response\n" if (defined $response);

sub timeout_command {
        my $timeout = (shift);
        my @command = @_;
        undef $@;
        my $return  = eval {
                local($SIG{ALRM}) = sub {die "timeout";};
                alarm($timeout);
                my $response;
                open(CMD, '-|', @command) || die "couldn't run @command: $!\n";
                while(<CMD>) {
                        $response .= $_;
                }
                close(CMD) || die "Couldn't close execution of @command: $!\n";
                $response;
        };
        alarm(0);
        if ($@) {
                warn "@cmd failure: $@\n";
        }
        return $return;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need a \n in the die message. (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

Answer (score 15):

There's a LOT of ways to do this:

- You can do this with a fork (perldoc -f fork)
- or using threads (perldoc threads). Both of these make passing the returned information back to the main program difficult.
- On systems that support it, you can set an alarm (perldoc -f alarm) and then clean up in the signal handler.
- You can use an event loop like POE or Coro.
- Instead of the backticks, you can use open() or respectively open2 or open3 (cf. IPC::Open2, IPC::Open3) to start a program while getting its STDOUT/STDERR via a file handle. Run non-blocking read operations on it. (perldoc -f select and probably google "perl nonblocking read")
- As a more powerful variant of the openX()'s, check out IPC::Run/IPC::Cmd.
- Probably tons I can't think of in the middle of the night.

Comment: On win32 systems watch out for broken `select` that works only for sockets and potentially weird interactions with console windows, wperl (runs perl in a non-console window way, but has weird effects on STDIO and child processes).  On the plus side you can do a `system(-1, 'foo')`.  Also, some ways of starting a process fail after running 64 children.  IME, `Win32::Process::Create()` is the safest way to run a program in the bgrnd.

Comment: @daotoad, thanks for that comment. My lack of win32 clue shows in that the only things I know is that fork() is emulated with threads and you can't use alarm. I guess if win32 is involved, IPC::Cmd would be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

If your external program doesn't take any input, look for the following words in the `perlipc` manpage:

> Here's a safe backtick or pipe open for read:

Use the example code and guard it with an alarm (which is also explained in `perlipc`).

Answer (score 2):

I coded below to run `rsync` on 20 directories simultaneously (in parallel instead of sequentially requiring me to wait hours for it to complete):

```perl
use threads;

for my $user ( keys %users ) {
  my $host = $users{$user};
  async {
    system <<~ "SHELL";
      ssh $host \\
        rsync_user $user
    SHELL
  }
}
```

```
$ pgrep -lf rsync | wc -l
      20
```

Not sure if it's best or even a good solution, but I was glad that it worked for my use case.

With this you get a mixed output on screen (what I ignored anyway), but it does its job successfully.

---

`threads` pragma exports the (very useful) [async](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads#async-BLOCK;) function by default.

`rsync_user` is my Perl script that wraps `rsync` command with options, and source and target directories set.

Ran on FreeBSD 13.1 with Perl 5.32.1