# alternative to sandboxing C for a programming contest with very limited constraints

Tags: c, security, parsing, sandbox

I'm trying to organize [a programming contest for signal processing](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/444.php); originally it was going to be in Python, but the question came up if I could expand allowable entries to C.

The type of programming needed for the entries is really pretty limited:

- no stdin/stdout needed
- contestants can declare 1 struct containing state variables
- entries can declare functions
- I will create my own trusted C code for a test harness that calls into the contestants' entries

So I am wondering: 
**is it possible to declare a particular C file as "safe" by parsing, if there are severe restrictions on the type of calculations allowed?** The one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to easily prevent casting pointers or pointer arithmetic.

Entries would be of this form (more or less):

```
#include "contest.h"
// includes stdint.h and math.h and some other things
// no "#" signs after this line allowed

typedef struct MyState {
  int16_t somevar;
  int16_t anothervar;
  ...
} MyState_t;

void dosomething(MyState *pstate)
{
  ...
}

void dosomethingelse(MyState *pstate)
{
  ...
}

void calculate_timestep(MyState *pstate, ContestResults *presults)
{
  ...
}
```

I've read some of the sandboxing questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980170/how-to-create-a-lightweight-c-code-sandbox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372939/organizing-programming-contest-howto-compile-and-execute?lq=1)) and it looks a bit difficult to find a way to sandbox one part of C code but allow other trusted parts of C code. So I'm hoping that parsing may be able to help "bless" C code that meets certain constraints.

Any advice? I don't really care if it gets stuck in an infinite loop (I can kill it if the time takes too long) but I do want to prevent OS access or unwanted memory access.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in allowing C if you also want to disallow things that are part of C, such as pointers, casting, and pointer arithmetic. Many valid C programs then become impossible to write, which would seem counter-intuitive if you're saying "you can use C".

It's hard to detect statically that a program won't do

```
*(uint32_t *) 0 = 0xdeadf00d;
```

which *might* cause a segmentation fault on your host operating system. I'm sure it's *possible*, or that very good attempts have been made. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2FC.2B.2B) has a list of C and C++ static checking tools that you can investigate.

Comment: Hmm, I disagree with your premise; a limited subset of C is still very useful, and all my entrants want is to be able to use portions of the language they know, rather than having to translate their thoughts into Python.